# Importing parts in Shape format

Tags: webots

I have a Catia Product design and I exported it in .wrl from Catia to import in Webots. The problem is all the parts are transformed to **Transforms** or **Groups** but I want them to be in **Shape** format to be able to fill the **boundingobject** part. I tried Blender also but it did not export in wrl format despite I adjusted in preferences. Can I apply **physics** without **boundingobject** part or without using **Shape**? Is there any option or condition for a part to be a **Shape** like it is physical or file size?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Blender version 2.79 which is able to export to VRML. As for the bounding object, I would recommend you to approximate it with a set of simple primitives (Spheres, Capsules, Boxes, Cylinder) rather than a mesh (IndexedFaceSet). That will produce a faster simulation and should be more stable as well.